Why is every matrix over an infinite field similar to a polynomial in a companion matrix?
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For $f \in K[x]$ be monic with degree $n$, let $C_f$ denote the companion matrix of $f$.
In this paper, the author says that it is easily seen that every matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form $g(C_f)$ for some $f$ if $K$ is infinite, where $g$ can be any polynomial in $K[x]$. How is this proved?
The only observation I have made is that the characteristic polynomial of $g(C_f)$ is $\prod_i (t - g(\alpha_i))$, where the $(\alpha_i)$ are the roots of $f$, so the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $(g(\alpha_i))$. I don't think this helps very much.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
As Ben Grossman surmises, the ideas in his proof can be used to obtain more general results. Here's a generalisation to the case when the characteristic polynomial of $\ A\ $ merely splits in $\ K\ ,$ and isn't restricted to being just an integral power of the indeterminate, as it is in his proof.  It certainly doesn't  make the result "easily seen", and I haven't been able to extend the proof to the case where not all of the roots of $\ A\text{'s}\ $ characteristic polynomial lie in $\ K\ .$   I'm guessing the ability to see the result "easily" might depend on some special knowledge of the properties of Frobenius normal forms and companion matrices which I don't possess.
My proof is based on the following observations:

Matrices with the same Jordan normal form are similar.
If $\ f(x)=\prod_\limits{i=1}^r\big(x-\rho_i\big)^{m_i}\ ,$ with $\ 
\rho_i\ne \rho_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ ,$ then a Jordan normal form for $\ C_f\ $ is
$$
\mathfrak{J}_{C_f}\ed\pmatrix{J_{m_1}\big(\rho_1\big)&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}&J_{m_2}\big(\rho_2\big)&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots&J_{m_r}\big(\rho_r\big)}\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
where
$$
J_k(\lambda)\ed\pmatrix{\lambda&1&0&&\dots&0&0\\
0&\lambda&1&&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&\lambda&&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&\dots&\lambda&1\\
0&0&0&\dots&\dots&0&\lambda}
$$
is a $\ k\times k\ $ Jordan block with main diagonal entries $\ \lambda\ .$
If $\ p\ $ is a polynomial, then\begin{align}p\big(J_k(\lambda)\big)&=\pmatrix{p(\lambda)&p'(\lambda)&p''(\lambda)&\dots&p^{(k-2)}(\lambda)&p^{(k-1)}(\lambda)\\
0&p(\lambda)&p'(\lambda)&\dots&p^{(k-3)}(\lambda)&p^{(k-2)}(\lambda)\\
0&0&p(\lambda)&\dots&p^{(k-4)}(\lambda)&p^{(k-3)}(\lambda)\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&p(\lambda)&p'(\lambda)\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&p(\lambda)}\\
&=p(\lambda)I_{k\times k}+\ \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=i+1}^{k-1}p^{(j-i)}(\lambda)e_ie_j^T ,\tag{2}\label{e2}\end{align}where $\ e_i\ $ is the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ column of the $\ k\times k\ $ identity matrix $\ I_{k\times k}\ .$That is, $\ p\big(J_k(\lambda)\big)\ $ is a $\ k\times k\ $ upper triangular matrix with entry $\ p^{(j-i)}(\lambda)\ $ in row $\ i\ $ and column $\ j\ $ for $\ 1\le i\le j\le k\ .$
If \begin{align}
B&=\pmatrix{b_0&b_1&b_2&\dots&b_{k-2}&b_{k-1}\\
0&b_0&b_1&\dots&b_{k-3}&b_{k-2}\\
0&0&b_0&\dots&b_{k-4}&b_{k-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&b_0&b_1\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&b_0}\\
&=b_0I_{k\times k}+\ \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=i+1}^{k-1}b_{j-i}e_ie_j^T\tag{3}\label{e3}\end{align}—that is, $\ B\ $ is a $\ k\times k\ $ upper triangular matrix with entry $\ b_{j-i}\ $ in row $\ i\ $ and column $\ j\ $ for $\ 1\le i\le j\le k\ $—and $\ b_1\ne0\ ,$ then $\ B\ $
has Jordan normal form $\ J_k\big(b_0\big)\ .$

The first two of the above observations are well known. For all I know, the other two might also qualify for that description, but if I've ever come across them before I'd long forgotten that encounter, and I had to (re?)discover and prove them for myself.
The idea of the overall proof is to take $\ f=\prod_\limits{i=1}^r\big(x-\rho_i\big)^{m_i}\ ,$ where the Jordan normal form of $\ A\ $ has $\ r\ $ blocks, $\ J_{m_1}(\lambda_1),$$\,J_{m_2}(\lambda_2),$$\,\dots,$$\,J_{m_r}(\lambda_r)\ ,$ and $\ \rho_1,\rho_2,\dots,\rho_r\ $ are any $\ r\ $ distinct elements of $\ K\ .$ This is the only part of the proof where the infinite cardinality of $\ K\ $ is invoked, and it would obviously be sufficient for $\ K\ $ to have cardinality at least $\ r\ $. Next, take $\ g\ $ to be a polynomial which satisfies the conditions
\begin{align}
g\big(\rho_i\big)&=\lambda_i\ \ \text{ and }\\
g'(\rho_i\big)&=1\tag{4}\label{e4}
\end{align}
for $\ 1\le i\le r\ .$ I give an explicit construction of such a polynomial below.  The Jordan normal form of $\ C_f\ $ is given by the expression \eqref{e1}. Therefore, there exist an invertible matrix $\ W\ $ such that
$$
W^{-1}C_fW=\mathfrak{J}_{C_f}\ ,
$$
and then
\begin{align}
W^{-1}g\big(C_f)W&=g\big(W^{-1}C_fW\big)\\
&=g\big(\mathfrak{J}_{C_f}\big)\\
&=\pmatrix{g\big(J_{m_1}\big(\rho_1\big)\big)&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}&g\big(J_{m_2}\big(\rho_2\big)\big)&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots&g\big(J_{m_r}\big(\rho_r\big)\big)}\\
&=\pmatrix{G_1&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}&G_2&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots&G_r}\ ,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
G_i&\ed\pmatrix{g\big(\rho_i\big)&g'\big(\rho_i\big)&g''\big(\rho_i\big)&\dots&g^{(m_i-2)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-1)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
0&g\big(\rho_i\big)&g'\big(\rho_i\big)&\dots&g^{(m_i-3)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-2)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
0&0&g\big(\rho_i\big)&\dots&g^{(m_i-4)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-3)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&g\big(\rho_i\big)&g'\big(\rho_i\big)\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&g\big(\rho_i\big)}\\
&=\pmatrix{\lambda_i&1&g''\big(\rho_i\big)&\dots&g^{(m_i-2)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-1)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
0&\lambda_i&1&\dots&g^{(m_i-3)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-2)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
0&0&\lambda_i&\dots&g^{(m_i-4)}\big(\rho_i\big)&g^{(m_i-3)}\big(\rho_i\big)\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&\lambda_i&1\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&\lambda_i}\ ,
\end{align}
by virtue of observation \eqref{e2} and the properties \eqref{e4} of $\ g\ .$ Now by observation \eqref{e3}, $\ G_i\ $ has Jordan normal form $\ J_{m_i}\big(\lambda_i\big)\ ,$ so there exists an invertible $\ m_i\times m_i\ $ matrix $\ U_i\ $ such that $\ U_i^{-1}G_iU_i=J_{m_i}\big(\lambda_i\big)\ .$ If we now define
$$
U\ed\pmatrix{U_1&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}&U_2&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots&U_r}
$$
then we have
\begin{align}
U^{-1}W^{-1}g\big(C_f)WU&=\pmatrix{U_1^{-1}G_1U_1&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}& U_2^{-1}G_2U_2&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots& U_r^{-1}G_rU_r}\\
&=\pmatrix{J_{m_1}\big(\lambda_1\big)&0_{m_1\times m_1}&\dots&0_{m_1\times m_1}\\
0_{m_2\times m_2}&J_{m_2}\big(\lambda_2\big)&\dots&0_{m_2\times m_2}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0_{m_r\times m_r}&0_{m_r\times m_r}&\dots&J_{m_r}\big(\lambda_r\big)}
\end{align}
which is the Jordan normal form of $\ A\ .$ Thus, it is also a Jordan normal form for $\ g\big(C_f\big)\ $ which must therefore be similar to $\ A\ .$
Here's the construction of $\ g\ $ promised above. Define
\begin{align}
h_1(x)&\ed\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{\lambda_i\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(x-\rho_j\big)}{\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)}\\
h_2(x)&\ed\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{\big(h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-1\big)\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(x-\rho_j\big)}{\left(\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)\right)^2}\\
h_3(x)&\ed\prod_{j=1}^r\big(x-\rho_j)\ \ \text{ and}\\
g(x)&\ed h_1(x)-h_2(x)h_3(x)\ .
\end{align}
The first two definitions use the Lagrange interpolation formula to obtain polynomials satisfying
\begin{align}
h_1\big(\rho_i\big)&=\lambda_i\ \ \ \text{ and}\\
h_2\big(\rho_i\big)&=\frac{h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-1}{\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)}
\end{align}
for $\ 1\le i\le r\ ,$ and $\ h_3\ $ has the properties
\begin{align}
h_3\big(\rho_i\big)&=0\ \ \ \text{ and}\\
h_3'\big(\rho_i\big)&=\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)
\end{align}
for $\ 1\le i\le r\ .$ Therefore
\begin{align}
g\big(\rho_i\big)&=h_1\big(\rho_i\big)-h_2\big(\rho_i\big)h_3\big(\rho_i\big)\\
&=h_1\big(\rho_i\big)\\
&=\lambda_i\ \ \ \text{ and}\\
g'\big(\rho_i\big)&=h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-h_2'\big(\rho_i\big)h_3\big(\rho_i\big)-h_2\big(\rho_i\big)h_3'\big(\rho_i\big)\\
&=h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-h_2\big(\rho_i\big)h_3'\big(\rho_i\big)\\
&=h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-\left(\frac{h_1'\big(\rho_i\big)-1}{\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)}\right)\prod_\limits{j=1,j\ne i}^r\big(\rho_i-\rho_j\big)\\
&=1
\end{align}
for $\ 1\le i\le r\ ,$ as required.
Here's a proof of observation \eqref{e2}. First, note that if $\ \pi_r(x)=x^r\ $ then
\begin{align}
\pi_r\big(J_k(\lambda)\big)&=\left(\lambda I_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}e_ie_{i+1}^T\right)^r\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^r {r\choose\ell}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}e_ie_{i+1}^T\right)^\ell\big(\lambda I_{k\times k}\big)^{r-\ell}\\
&=\lambda^rI_{k\times k}+\sum_{\ell=1}^{\min(r,k-1)} {r\choose\ell}\lambda^{r-\ell}\sum_{i=1}^{k-\ell}e_ie_{i+\ell}^T\,^\color{red}{\dagger}\\
&=\lambda^rI_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{\ell=1}^{\min(r,k-i)}{r\choose\ell}\lambda^{r-\ell}e_ie_{i+\ell}^T\\
&=\lambda^rI_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{\ell=1}^{k-i}\pi_r^{(\ell)}(\lambda)e_ie_{i+\ell}^T\\
&=\pi_r(\lambda) I_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^k\pi_r^{(j-i)}(\lambda)e_ie_j^T\ ,
\end{align}
which establishes the observation for $\ p=\pi_r\ .$ For an arbitrary polynomial, $\ p(\lambda)=\sum_\limits{r=0}^dp_r\lambda^r=\sum_\limits{r=0}^dp_r\pi_r(\lambda)\ ,$ we therefore have
\begin{align}
p(J_k(\lambda)\big)&=\sum_{r=0}^dp_rJ_k(\lambda)^r\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^dp_r\pi_r\big(J_k(\lambda)\big)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^dp_r\left(\pi_r(\lambda) I_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^k\pi_r^{(j-i)}(\lambda)e_ie_j^T\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{r=0}^dp_r\pi_r(\lambda)\right) I_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^k\left(\sum_{r=0}^dp_r\pi_r^{(j-i)}(\lambda)\right)e_ie_j^T\\
&=p(\lambda) I_{k\times k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^kp^{(j-i)}(\lambda)e_ie_j^T\ ,
\end{align}
which establishes the observation for $\ p\ .$
Observation \eqref{e3} follows from the fact that both the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $\ B\ $ are $\ \big(x-b_0\big)^k\ .$ Obviously, $\ \det\big(xI_{k\times k}-B\big)=\big(x-b_0\big)^k\ ,$ and since the minimal polynomial must be a factor of this, it must have the form $\ \big(x-b_0\big)^j\ $ for some $\ j\le k\ .$ But since $\ \big(B-b_0I_{k\times k}\big)^{k-1}=b_1^{k-1}e_1e_k^T\ne0\ ,$ it follows that the minimal polynomial of $\ B\ $ must also be $\ \big(x-b_0\big)^k\ .$
If the characteristic polynomial $\ c_A\ $ of $\ A\ $ doesn't split in $\ A\ ,$ the proof will still obviously work with $\ K\ $ replaced by the splitting field, $\ K_{c_A}\ ,$ of $\ c_A\ ,$ but without some extra work, you'll only get similarity over $\ K_{c_A}\ ,$ not necessarily over $\ K\ ,$ and it's not clear that you can choose both polynomials $\ f\ $ and $\ g\ $ to lie in $\ K[x]\ $ rather than $\ K_{c_A}[x]\ .$  It's not hard to choose $\ f\ $ to be in $\ K[x]\ ,$  but I haven't been able to show that you can do the same with $\ g\ .$ Doing that would be sufficient to prove the general case, because if $\ f,g\in K[x]\ ,$ then the entries in the matrices $\ C_f,g\big(C_f\big)\ $ and the Frobenius normal form of $\ g\big(C_f\big)\ $ would all lie in $\ K\ .$ Since $\ A\ $ and $\ g\big(C_f\big)\ $ (hypothetically) have the same Jordan normal form, then they must also have the same Frobenius normal form, and since they're similar over $\ K\ $ to their Frobenius normal forms, they would also have to be similar to each other over $\ K\ .$
$\,^\color{red}{\dagger}$ Using the identity
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}e_ie_{i+1}^T\right)^\ell=\cases{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{k-
\ell}e_ie_{i+\ell}&if $\ \ell\le k-1$\\
0_{k\times k}&if $\ \ell\ge k$}
$$
which is easily established by induction.

Thank you for the answer. It looks quite intimidating at first with all of the matrices displayed in full, but you make the derivations look effortless, especially that one for $g$!

The following is incomplete but potentially helpful. I suspect that there is some nice way to generalize this to arbitrary matrices $A$, but the below addresses only the case where $A$ is nilpotent.

Here's an argument that works over $\Bbb C$; I suspect it could be generalized to work over other infinite fields.
Let $A \sim B$ mean "$A$ is similar to $B$". First of all, note that $g(PCP^{-1}) = Pg(C)P^{-1}$, so the following statements are equivalent:

Every $A \sim g(C_f)$ for some $f$
Every $A = g(M_f)$, where $M_f\sim C_f$ for some $f$
Every $A \sim g(M_f)$, where $M_f \sim C_f$ for some $f$

As I note here, a matrix $M$ is similar to a companion matrix if and only if the Jordan form of $M$ has one Jordan block associated with each eigenvalue. I will call matrices that are similar to a companion matrix "non-derogatory".
Now, we begin with the case where $A$ has zero as its only eigenvalue, and assume without loss of generality that $A$ is in Jordan form. Let $J_k(\lambda)$ denote the size-$k$ Jordan block associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$. I will make use of the following facts.

Claim: If $g'(\lambda) \neq 0$, then $g(J_k(\lambda))$ is similar to $J_k(g(\lambda))$.
Corollary: If $A$ is a matrix with zero as its only eigenvalue (i.e. $A$ is nilpotent) and $g'(0) \neq 0$, then $g(A) \sim A + g(0)I$.

We proceed inductively: if $A$ consists of only one Jordan block, then it is similar to a companion matrix, and we are done. Otherwise, it is of the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{J_k(0) & 0\\0 & A_0},
$$
where $A_0$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue. Let $M_0, g_0$ be such that $M_0$ is non-derogatory and $A_0 \sim g_0(M_0)$.
Let $M_1$ be the matrix
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{J_k(\lambda) & 0\\0 & M_0},
$$
where $\lambda$ is non-zero, $g_0(\lambda) \neq 0$, and $g_0'(\lambda) \neq 0$.  We have
$$
g_0(M_1) = \pmatrix{g_0(J_k(\lambda)) & 0\\0 & g_0(M_0)},
$$
where we note that $g_0(J_k(\lambda)) \sim J_k(g_0(\lambda))$ and $g_0(M_0) \sim A_0$. If $n$ denotes the size of $A_0$, We have
$$
(g_0(M_1))^n = \pmatrix{[g_0(J_k(\lambda))]^n & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
Note that $[g_0(J_k(\lambda))]^n \sim J_k([g_0(\lambda)]^n)$, and $[g_0(\lambda)]^n \neq 0$. Now, construct a polynomial $h$ such that $h(0) = 0$, $h([g_0(\lambda)]^n) = 0$, and $h'([g_0(\lambda)]^n) \neq 0$. We have
$$
h((g_0(M_1))^n) = \pmatrix{h([g_0(J_k(\lambda))]^n) & 0\\0 & 0},
$$
where we note that $h([g_0(J_k(\lambda))]^n) \sim J_k(h([g_0(\lambda)]^n) = J_k(0)$.
On the other hand, if we denote $p(x) = (x - g_0(x))^k - (-g_0(\lambda))^k$, then we have
$$
p(g_0(M_1)) = \pmatrix{- (-g_0(\lambda))^k I & 0\\0 & p(g_0(M))},
$$
where we note (using the Corollary) that $p(g_0(M)) \sim A_0$.
Now, construct a polynomial $q$ such that $q(-(-g_0(\lambda))^k) = q(0) = 0$, but $q'(0) \neq 0$. Conclude that
$$
q(p(g_0(M_1))) = \pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & q(p(g_0(M_0)))},
$$
where we note that $q(p(g_0(M_0))) \sim p(g_0(M_0)) \sim A_0$.
Finally, denote
$$
g_1(x) = h((g_0(x))^n) + q(p(g_0(x))).
$$
We have
$$
g_1(x) = \pmatrix{h([g_0(J_k(\lambda))]^n) & 0\\
0 & q(p(g_0(M_0)))} \sim \pmatrix{J_k(0) & 0\\0 & A_0} = A.
$$

Thank you for the answer! I'll try to read this as soon as possible.

Hi Ben, apologies for the late reply, I ended up on hiatus from mathematics. I noted two minor misprints -- $p(g_0(M_0)) \sim A$ instead of $p(g_0(M)) \sim A$ halfway through and $g_1(M_0)$ instead of $g_1(x)$ on LHS of the last line. I followed everything except the computation of $p(g_0(J_k(\lambda)))$, but perhaps I need a few more minutes.

I think I see: the constant term [coeff. of $I$] in $(g_0(J_k(\lambda)) - g_0(g_0(J_k(\lambda)))$ cancels out. Then, every term in the polynomial expansion has a factor of the $k$-nilpotent matrix $J_k(\lambda)$. Thanks again!
